# make vertical div of random height scrollable if bigger than parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm struggling with this case where I have two div in a column.

The first one (`#first`) will be small, but I cannot know its height in advance. Its content should always be displayed, without scrollbars.

The second one (`#second`) will be long (in fact, this will be a table). So I'd like it to be scrollable when it becomes too big.

The container of those two div (`#container`) takes 100% of the available height, and cannot take more.

I'm not sure if I need flexboxes or not. And I'm not sure if this behaviour is possible without setting a height to `#first`.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="first">
    Some random stuff (but should be small)<br>
    Like few lines<br>
    No more
  </div>
  <div id="second">
    <div id="content">
      This can be very very<br>
      very very<br>
      very long
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: solid black 1px;
}

#first {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: cyan;
}

#second {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: pink;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

This [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6Loaod80/) will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add `flex: 1; overflow: auto` the `#second`, it will fill the available space of its parent, and when its content gets too big, it will scroll.

*For this demo to work, so the `height: 100%` set on `container` will have from where to get its 100%, I also added `height: 100%` to the `html` and `body`.*

Stack snippet

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;                  /*  added  */
  margin: 0;                     /*  added  */
}
#container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: solid black 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#first {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: cyan;
}

#second {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: pink;

  flex: 1;                       /*  added  */
  overflow: auto;                /*  added  */
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="first">
    Some random stuff (but should be small)<br>
    Like few lines<br>
    No more
  </div>
  <div id="second">
    <div id="content">
      This can be very very<br>
      very very<br>
      very long
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```